# How to do background sync for contacts when app is in active state in ios swift?

Tags: ios, swift, synchronization, contacts

i am able to sync Phone contacts in App but i need phone contacts should sync in background to app.

like below in android

[image]

I am able to sync Normally with below code:

```
  func getLocalContacts(completion:@escaping contacts) {
    let contacts     = CNContact()
    let contactStore = CNContactStore()
    let keys    = [CNContactGivenNameKey,CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey]//[CNContactFormatter.descriptorForRequiredKeys(for: .fullName),CNContactPhoneNumbersKey] as [Any]
    let request = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: keys as! [CNKeyDescriptor])
    do {
        try contactStore.enumerateContacts(with: request) {(contact, stop) in
            completion(contact)
        }
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        completion(contacts)
    }
}



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return contacts.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell: ContactsTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ContactsTableViewCell") as! ContactsTableViewCell
    cell.nameLbl.text    = contacts[indexPath.row].givenName + " " + contacts[indexPath.row].familyName
    cell.empRoleLbl.text = contacts[indexPath.row].phoneNumbers.first?.value.stringValue
    print("table phnums \(contacts[indexPath.row].phoneNumbers.first?.value.stringValue)")
    cell.inviteButn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(connected(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    return cell

}
```

or how to use GCD to sync contacts
Please help me to sync contacts backgroud when app is in active state.

Comment: hello please help to share your knowledge please

Comment: Can't understand from your question; What does sync mean? you are just fetching contacts from the phone. Then you want to be able to sync your contact on a background thread or when your app is in the background state?

Comment: @MahsaYousefi, yes i am able to fetch contacts.. but i need to sync that contacts in  background like above mentioned android app